# Одинаковое название у переменных в main и аргументах функции

Tags: c++

Является ли ошибкой использование одинаковых названий для переменных в main и аргументов функций, при условии, что доступ к переменным в main не нужен?

Например:

```
void show_time(int hours, int minutes)
{
    //код
}

int main()
{
    int hours, minutes;
    show_time(hours, minutes)
}
```

Comment: Нет. Не является.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не ошибка, а вполне нормальная практика. Эти переменные находятся в разных областях видимости, и между собой никак не связаны (не считая передачи параметров, конечно). Именно в данном случае выбор одинаковых имен только улучшает понимание программы, придумывать отличающиеся имена нет никакой необходимости.